# Planet of the Apes tags

Tags: discussion, tags

There are some questions about various movies in the *Planet of the Apes* franchise, in particular about the original as well as the 2001 remake, both directly titled *Planet of the Apes*, and some about the new franchise, i.e. the movies *Rise of the...* and *Dawn of the...*. Seeing that they were all tagged [planet-of-the-apes](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planet-of-the-apes) I retagged the questions about the new movies with [rise-planet-of-the-apes](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rise-planet-of-the-apes) and [dawn-planet-of-the-apes](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dawn-planet-of-the-apes) respectively, to reflect the actual titles more thoroughly.

But I see that this strategy is not that optimal regarding precision and reading pleasure (though, neither would [rise-of-planet-of-apes](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rise-of-planet-of-apes) be) and not too future proof either, given that it already scratches the 25 charater limit and previous (and possible future) movies in the franchise would already blast it with this minimal strategy.

So what would be the best strategy to tag those questions?

- Should the current (or by me prematurely employed) strategy of using [rise-planet-of-the-apes](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rise-planet-of-the-apes) and similar tags be left as is and adapted when the need arises (or for individual movies only)?
- Should they just all be tagged with a general [planet-of-the-apes](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planet-of-the-apes) applying to the whole franchise?
- Or should we chose a completely different tagging strategy (dropping more filling words, abbreviation (oh, please not), or pleading the SE staff for a less stupid tag name limit (probably the best but least fruitful strategy))?

Comment: Mmm especially since the 1968 movie is just entitled "Planet of the apes" - I think retagging them was the best thing to do.  I might open a question specifically asking for a larger tag limit.

Comment: @iandotkelly Well, good luck. I think that would require a change to the whole system (which isn't too likely, and has IMHO been adressed previously). But maybe if one achieves to limit the proposal for this site only (if possible at all). But then again, I'm not sure the higher powers would want such precedence cases. But it's indeed a repeated problem, and maybe to some degree one geniune to this site, given the title tag policy.

Comment: I know its unlikely, but I don't know what limits are simply configurable from site to site basis.  If I don't ask, it never gets added to the backlog.  Even 1 more character would help for some tags.  I know its unlikely but I'll try.

Comment: @iandotkelly Well, you have my dearest support on this, feel free to share the link to the respective question once asked.

Comment: I read somewhere that the next movie will also titled as [tag:planet-of-the-apes] hehehhehe 3rd duplicate. Year appending is best but something should be done for rise-off, dawn-of,escape-from etc etc. Can we use abbreviation like scifi use?

Comment: @AnkitSharma *"Can we use abbreviation?"* - No, we can't! ;-( (What'd that be anyway, `pota`, `rotpota`, `dotpota`? bleh!)

Answer (score 1):

I deliberately ignored the Planet of the Apes tag when going for Research Assistant because of this issue. Personally I think we should use [planet-of-the-apes](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planet-of-the-apes) for the franchise, and create new more specific tags for everything that has the same name:

- [planet-of-the-apes-1968](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planet-of-the-apes-1968) For the original
- [planet-of-the-apes-2001](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planet-of-the-apes-2001) For the remake
- [planet-of-the-apes-tv](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planet-of-the-apes-tv) For the TV show, if we ever get a question about it.

Which all fit with the limit. As for the sequels, unfortunately I think every solution is a bad one. People are probably going to start typing "Rise of" or "Dawn of" and get nothing.

There's got to be some leway with the tag names though, because as you can see from the [data explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/new) tags are stored in a `nvarchar (150)`, and as there's a limit of 5 tags per question, which are each stored in between angle brackets (`<` and `>`) (as you can verify by looking at [this exported query result](http://data.stackexchange.com/movies/csv/271319) from [a data exchange query](http://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/208348/longest-tag)). So the used characters for each row are at most:

```
(25 chars per tag + 2 brackets) * 5 tag limit = 135 chars
```

Which means there's 15 chars which are free in the tag section and could be allocated with some special longer tags which I believe mods should be able to create. This would allow us to create a single longer tag for those movies, such as [escape-from-the-planet-of-the-apes](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/escape-from-the-planet-of-the-apes) and [conquest-of-the-planet-of-the-apes](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conquest-of-the-planet-of-the-apes) which are tied for the longest names in the series. These would then be:

```
(34 char special tag + 2 for brackets) + ((25 chars per tag + 2 brackets) * 4 additional tag limit) = 144 chars
```

Which will still allow the tags to safely fit in the database without any changes required to the structure.

Comment: I'm yet unsure what to think about your general suggestion at the end, seeing that this shouldn't really amount to any mod overhead or special treatment. But I've long wanted to propose some special treatment for movie tags anyway (once the system might be more customizable after graduation) and maybe one could combine this with your idea. The year appendage for the remake is a good idea (and it's even applied policy, I wonder how I missed that), and maybe also the franchise tag in combination with the specific tags.